# How to get the changes from other person's workspace in Accurev?

Tags: accurev

There are some changes in other person's AccuRev workspace. I can't promote these changes, because there is an overlap. I can't resolve the overlap, because the workspace is not mine. I can't cross-promote these changes, because apparently such functionality doesn't work with workspaces. I'd prefer not to reattach the workspace to my PC, because such action would disrupt the workflow of the other person.

I want to get these changes into my own workspace.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a few ways.

1. By file:
   For each file you want, in your workspace, select the file -> open the "version browser" -> select the version of the file from the other workspace -> right click -> You can either "Send to Workspace", Patch or Merge.
2. By Transaction:
   Right click on the other users workspace -> Show History -> Select the transaction you want that includes the changes -> Right click -> Send to Workspace -> Pick your destination workspace.